# While editing the meeting on the calendar stop notifying everyone outlook?

Tags: outlook

While editing the meeting on the outlook calendar all assign users are getting the mail every-time when i am performing any action on the meeting.  I don't wan't to send the mail while editing the meeting. so is there have any option to stop the mails to the users while editing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to handle the `ItemSend` event in a VBA macro or add-in where you can filter outgoing emails. For example, a simple VBA macro shows how to prevent items from being sent out:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
 
 Dim prompt As String 
 
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
 
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 
   Cancel = True 
 End If 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I can use this? can you please explain more?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) is the starting point for VBA macros.